# Realm database - field of type x is not supported

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

im working with realm in android and im getting this error message:
error: Field "items" of type "java.util.List" is not supported.

it's at this line:

```
private List<Item> items;
```

here is the class:

```
public class Article extends RealmObject implements Serializable{

@PrimaryKey
private String category;
private List<Item> items;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

}

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately RealmDatabase doesn’t support 
`List<>`. But you can achieve the same result by Using `RealmList` :)

> Realm supports subclasses of RealmObject and RealmList to model relationships.

From: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest